# textField in a tableViewCell clears the value when Scrolling off screen

Tags: ios4

I have a textField inside a tableViewCell. I recently noticed that if I enter a value in the textBox, and then scroll the cell off the screen, the value in the textbox disappears.

please someone help me out for how to store the values temporarily.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bks when scroll back, in datasource function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the textfield is reused.
So what u need to do is save the textbox's text value while editing, and assign the value to this textbox(or should call it textfield) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

see the UITextfield delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```